# MySql decimal type display problem

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I store money values in my db table. E.g. I have `2.50`. But when I print that value the 0 is always missing so I get `2.5`. The db table money field has the following type: `decimal(6,2)`

any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default PHP `echo` and `print` don't print the trailing zeros of a floating point number.

To overcome this you need to use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) as:

```
$money = 2.50;

printf("%.2f",$money); // prints 2.50

echo $money;           // prints 2.5
print $money;          // prints 2.5
```

The format specifier used in `printf` is `"%.2f"` what it means is always print **atleast** two digits after the decimal point and if there are not so many digits use `0`. 
Note that it is atleast two digits not **equal** to two digits. So if I print `1.234` with that format it will **not truncate** it to `1.23` but will print `1.234` and if I print `1` it will result in `1.00`